# what is the meaning of tags in csv files from autoware semantic maps

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I started working with autoware because I want to use the semantic map for my research in indoor robotics, however I cant find information relate to it, how it is built and the tags that are used, for example for the lane.csv the columns have names like lno, lanecfgfg, etc. How do I know what these tags mean and how the car uses it?

Is it there a document where I can find the architecture of how the semantic maps are being created and consumed?

I appreciate your help, thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323841/what-is-the-meaning-of-tags-in-csv-files-from-autoware-semantic-maps/) by [jose.rincon](https://answers.ros.org/users/41764/jose.rincon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Do you mean vector map??
It is internal format of a map company in Japan.(https://www.aisantec.co.jp/english/)
We also think using internal format is very very bad in terms of usability of Autoware.
So, we are talking about changing to other open map format such as OpenDrive,Lanelet.
(https://discourse.ros.org/t/autoware-tsc-meeting-minutes-for-april-17th-2019/8938)

---

Originally posted by [Masaya Kataoka](https://answers.ros.org/users/41502/masaya-kataoka/) with karma: 111 on 2019-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jose.rincon](https://answers.ros.org/users/41764/jose.rincon/) on 2019-05-26**:
thank you for your answer

**Comment by [GaoRui](https://answers.ros.org/users/56475/gaorui/) on 2020-07-08**:
Hi! I can not find more information about in “https://www.aisantec.co.jp/english/”，Would you mind providing more specific weblink ？Thanks！